# Optimisation problem involving factorials(optimise a product of factorials)

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, permutations, combinations, nonlinear-optimization

I have 4 variables.

$A= l{nq\choose l} {n(1-q)\choose n(1-q)-np+l}$

$B=(np-l){nq\choose l} {n(1-q)\choose n(1-q)-np+l}$

$C=(nq-l){nq\choose l} {n(1-q)\choose n(1-q)-np+l}$

$D=(n(1-q)-np+l){nq\choose l} {n(1-q)\choose n(1-q)-np+l}$

$l$ goes from $0$ to $np$, $p$ and $q$ are probabilities. So for example,  $p=0.2, q=0.6, n=15$, we have $np=3, nq=9,n(1-q)=6,n(1-p)=12$.Also $np<nq$. When $np,nq,n(1-p), n(1-q)$ are fractions they are rounded off to their nearest whole number.

How can we optimise $A,B,C,D$ with respect to $l$ such that they try to attain their maximum value?
One way I thought of was to maximise the product ABCD, find the $l$ for which $ABCD$ is maximum. As an example I tried for $n=15, p =0.2, q=0.6$ case.

I found that this maximum is occurs at $l=1.815$, but this is just by using Mathematica. How can I do this algebraically? I see that this $l=1.815$ is close to $npq$, Basically how can I get a general result for the $l$ corresponding to the maximum value of the $ABCD$ product in terms of n,p and q?

Comment: In stead of asking the same question again, you should edit your original question. Also note that I have given a general trick in the comments there that solves all four.

Comment: It wasn't the same question. I do understand individually how to do it. For each of the terms. I wanted to optimise all of them at the same time.

Comment: You can optimize the product by the same method, i.e. considering the ratio of consecutive values. The resulting rational function will be of high degree, but you get some of the factorization for free, as it is already written as a product. Overall, it should be completely possible, though dull and laborious, to do it by hand.

Comment: Can you give a simple example illustrating this?

Comment: Take the ratio of the products $\frac{A_{l+1}B_{l+1}C_{l+1}D_{l+1}}{A_lB_lC_lD_l}$ and ask when it becomes less than $1$. Its a laborious calculation, so I don't really feel like doing it for you, I'm afraid :-). It's the kind of thing you'd usually get a computer to do for you.

Comment: No, no. This much is good enough. I wanted some clarification on what you meant. I tried stirling approximation too. It is laborious xD

Comment: How do you proceed after that? So you get $A_{l}> A_{l+1}$ for some l, and the maximum was attained just before this  $l$?